# Getting runtime exception in eureka server

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client instance has been closed.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.guava.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:169) ~[jersey-common-3.1.5.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.checkNotClosed(JerseyClient.java:248) ~[jersey-client-3.1.5.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.getConfiguration(JerseyClient.java:363) ~[jersey-client-3.1.5.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.getConfiguration(JerseyClient.java:54) ~[jersey-client-3.1.5.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey3.EurekaJersey3ClientImpl$ConnectionCleanerTask.run(EurekaJersey3ClientImpl.java:347) ~[eureka-client-jersey3-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

how to fix this ?